# Angular Form submit button only fires on second click

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, form-submit, ng-submit

I'm building a small webpage that does some queries to an API. The query happens when the submit button is hit, if all entered data is valid. However at some point when I was adjusting the form from a set of separate elements (textbox, selectbox, button), I started having to hit "Search" once, and then hit it again for the function to fire.

What is going on/how do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="search" class="centerWrapper">
    <div id="searchArea" class="searchArea">
        <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="charName" ng-model="charName" placeholder="Character Name"></input>
        <select class="selectBox" ng-model="selectedRealm" name="selectedRealm" ng-options="realm.name for realm in realmList">
            <option value="" class="realmPlaceholder" disabled selected>Select Realm Name</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" ng-click="buttonpress(charName, selectedRealm)" class="searchButton">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.buttonpress = function(charName, realmName){
    if(typeof charName === "undefined" || charName.includes("world") || typeof realmName === "undefined"){
        alert("Please enter a valid Character Name and Realm.")
    } else {
        var request = {name: charName, realm: realmName};
        $http.post('/buttonpress', request)
        .then(function(response) {
            alert(response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
input.searchButton {
    text-align: center;
    width: 79%;
    background-color: #128880;
    color:#ACC8C9;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 22%;
}

input.searchButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(1, 92, 196)
}

input.searchButton:active {
    background-color: #134b58;
    box-shadow: 0 5px rgb(102, 102, 102);
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

NOTE: I've noticed this is also only upon starting the page and refreshing.

Comment: Does it fire alert on first hit ?

Comment: @Doomenik Nope the alert doesn't trigger until the 2nd hit. And that's regardless of whether I leave the fields blank or fill them out.

Comment: your HTML looks malformed.  you have `<input ...></button>`.  is that a typo?

Comment: @Claies yes that was a typo. Unfortunately didn't fix the issue :| will correct that typo in the post too.

Comment: There are more typos, your also not closing your input charname. Recommend doing it like `<input type=""....  />`

Comment: @Doomenik oh wow.. thanks for the catch. I guess I'm starting to suffer from lack of sleep.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle I have created http://jsfiddle.net/0czwfs08/ . The http call is removed and it is working one first click.I did some minor changes in the html code.

Comment: well I figured out the issue and posted the answer to the question... I'm so sorry I wasted your time. Thank you all for the help though! I didn't realize how deadly a problem typos could be on no sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. This is why it's a bad idea to code until 4:30AM. Some stupid mistakes are going to happen:

```
$scope.buttonpress = function() {
    $scope.buttonpress = function(){
        if(typeof $scope.charName === "undefined" || $scope.charName.includes(";") || typeof $scope.selectedRealm === "undefined"){
            alert("Please enter a valid Character Name and Realm.")
        } else {
            var request = {name: $scope.charName, realm: $scope.selectedRealm};
            $http.post('/buttonpress', request)
            .then(function(response) {
                // alert(response.data);
                debugger;
                $scope.showBoard = true;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer to the mystery: somehow I put buttonPress inside another buttonPress.. whoops.